# Powershell method to purge cache files from a DNN installation

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a method to purge cache files programtically using PowerShell for a DNN install. There are multiple directories with cached pages based on a portal ID number. I'm looking to use regular expression to loop through each directory and purge the files in it. Here is an example of what the directories:

```
D:\MySites\Portals\1\Cache\Pages
D:\MySites\Portals\174\Cache\Pages
D:\MySites\Portals\12\Cache\Pages
```

etc

The number in between Portals and Cache will be no more than 3 digits (1 - 999).

I have a GCI recursive script but it doesn't quite work as expected. I don't want to have a list of all the directories as I've demonstrated above because it will be a huge list. INstead, I want to iterate through each Portal directory that has a number only (not _Default or another name specifically - only numbered directories) and purge the files.

```
gci -r D:\MySites\Portals\"[0-9][0-9]"\Cache\Pages | where -FilterScript  | remove-item -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Confirm:$false
```

Any tips would be great (i'm stuck with the correct Regex and -FilterScript where clause.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without spending too much time trying to figure out the regex for all three, just run three lines for each scenario:

`gci -r "D:\MySites\Portals\[0-9]\Cache\Pages" | remove-item -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Confirm:$false`

`gci -r "D:\MySites\Portals\[0-9][0-9]\Cache\Pages" | remove-item -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Confirm:$false`

`gci -r "D:\MySites\Portals\[0-9][0-9][0-9]\Cache\Pages" | remove-item -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Confirm:$false`

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing this "gci -r D:\MySites\Portals\[0-9][0-9]\Cache\Pages | where-object {$_.extension -eq ".resources"} | remove-item -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Confirm:$false -whatif"

After quickly confirming what .resources files were going to be purged, i remove the -whatif. Works, thanks again.

Comment: @Mike J cool glad I could help. That should cover cases like Portals92 but does it cover Portals092 and Portals9??

Comment: Exactly, so I modify it by adding another [0-9][0-9]

Comment: Ok just checking.. nice! I'm sure there is a regex that handles all three cases but I was having trouble getting it to work within the file path

Answer (score -1):

You could just do it the easy way...

```
gci -r 'D:\MySites\Portals\*\Cache\Pages'  | remove-item -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: Hi Dallas, that won't work because there are directories in \Portals\ which are not numbers as well. I only want to purge files in directories as per the examples above.